Attach several files into mail from Google Form
So at the moment I have a working script that makes sending an email automatically from Google Forms to mail, it also attaches one file when is uploaded in the form but if I upload 2 files or more it will only attach one, I think it is easy to fix but I have no clue on it!
Here is my code of the part that is working:
var filetomail = DriveApp.getFileById(answers["XXXXX"][0]);

MailApp.sendEmail({
      name: "Mailing",
      to: xxxx,
      cc: xxxx,
      subject: "xxxx",
      htmlBody: "<p>xxxx" +,
      noReply: true,
      attachments: [filetomail.getBlob()]
    }

I already tried adding a second filetomail2 for example, and it only works if 2 files are uploaded but not all the times the form is needed with 2 files, usually are from 1 to 5 files and I would need all of them to be attached into the mail.

Get Multiple Attachment in a single file
Due to lack of information with your code.
I added an implementation using onFormSubmit
Create a trigger
Set onFormSubmit as the function and "From form" -> "On form submit" as the event type.
For this approach
for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
        var item = responses[i];
        
        if (item.getItem().getType() === FormApp.ItemType.FILE_UPLOAD) {
          var fileUrls = item.getResponse();
          
          if (Array.isArray(fileUrls)) {
            for (var j = 0; j < fileUrls.length; j++) {
              var fileId = getFileIdFromUrl(fileUrls[j]);
              var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
              attachments.push(file.getBlob());
            }
          } else {
            var fileId = getFileIdFromUrl(fileUrls);
            var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
            attachments.push(file.getBlob());
          }
        }
      }

The outer for loop iterates through all responses to find file uploads.
It checks if each response item is a file upload.
If only a single file was uploaded, it processes that file and adds it to the attachments array.
This array of file blobs (attachments) is then used to attach files to an email
Second Approach:
function getFileIdFromUrl(url) {
  var match = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  return match ? match[0] : null;
}

Use a helper function to extract file IDs from file URLs.
Script Used:
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var attachments = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    var item = responses[i];
    
    if (item.getItem().getType() === FormApp.ItemType.FILE_UPLOAD) {
      var fileUrls = item.getResponse();
      
      if (Array.isArray(fileUrls)) {
        for (var j = 0; j < fileUrls.length; j++) {
          var fileId = getFileIdFromUrl(fileUrls[j]);
          var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
          attachments.push(file.getBlob());
        }
      } else {
        var fileId = getFileIdFromUrl(fileUrls);
        var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
        attachments.push(file.getBlob());
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    name: "Mailing",
    to: 'sample@google.com',
    subject: "Subject of the email",
    htmlBody: "<p>Body of the email</p>",
    noReply: true,
    attachments: attachments
  });
}


function getFileIdFromUrl(url) {
  var match = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);
  return match ? match[0] : null;
}

Sample Output
Google Form

Email Received

Feel free to use this code as your reference.As this code might not be directly compatible with your current project feel free to comment any questions.
Reference :

GetItemresponses
event type

